# Invalid Continuation token CosmosDB

Tags: c#, pagination, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am running an Azure Function which queries an instance of a CosmosDB.

I am trying to implement pagination with the Continuation Token, but I keep on getting the following response when calling my function with the continuation token:

> Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "Invalid Continuation Token\r\nActivityId: 0f79a65f-a9d2-49a8-8a9c-d33a8526bec8, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.0.0.0, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/1.22.0 Host/32-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0

Here is my Azure function: This function will initially be called with no token, and on request of second page, the token will be passed in.

```
[FunctionName("GetAllPaged")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReadAll(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "GetAllPaged/{pageSize?}/{token?}")]HttpRequestMessage req,
    int? pageSize, string token, ILogger log, [Inject]IComponent<EventModel> component)
{
    try
    {
        log.LogInformation("Get all events");

        var response = await component.GetAll_Paged(pageSize, token);

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
        return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

On my initial call to my Azure Function, using the url http://localhost:7071/api/Event/GetAllPaged/3, I get the following response:

```
    {
"Continuation": {
    "token": "CDhbANnikwAGAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "range": {
        "min": "",
        "max": "FF"
    }
},
"Results": [
    {
        "id": "c428e1c4-48d5-47ae-9f37-c29cc3fc8696",
        "Description": "Test description nr: 64791",
        "User": "Test User"
    },
    {
        "id": "bab08fe7-da5c-48c6-971d-a14ef3eb5f4c",
        "Description": "Test description nr: 63486",
        "User": "Test User"
    },
    {
        "id": "9688acc2-4acf-4acd-a252-5481b5b4d450",
        "Description": "Test description nr: 86498",
        "User": "Test User"
    }
]
}
```

When I use the token provided in my next request to the Azure function, using the url with token http://localhost:7071/api/Event/GetAllPaged/3/CDhbANnikwAGAAAAAAAAAA==, I get the error as listed above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please share the main code of `GetAll_Paged` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found my mistake.

I needed to pass the whole continuation json object received back to azure, instead of only extracting the token.

Instead of passing through:

> CDhbANnikwAGAAAAAAAAAA==

I should have passed through the entire JSON object/string returned, as follow:

> "{\"token\":\"CDhbANnikwAIAAAAAAAAAA==\",\"range\":{\"min\":\"\",\"max\":\"FF\"}}"